# After pro guarding the release app still see logs

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

Could you please help me since I am super confused. After signing my release APK I install the application but I can still see logs.

I have the following in **build.gradle**:

```
release {
   minifyEnabled true
   shrinkResources false
   debuggable false
   testCoverageEnabled false
   zipAlignEnabled true
   jniDebuggable false

   proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

my `proguard-rules.pro` has this content:

```
-dontwarn **
-target 1.7
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/allocation/variable
-keep class **
-keepclassmembers class *{*;}
-keepattributes *

#This will remove log
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
   public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
```

after running the app logs clearly visible in Android Monitor:

```
11-06 12:29:03.306 18976-19064/? E/from getCookieList: Cookies: {......}
```

I see all error logs which made by me! Shouldn't the error logs be removed?

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: Guys, please help me out with this since I just can't get it why I am still see my Log.e() logs in release build!

Answer (score 1):

You turned off proguard optimization by using this flag `-dontpreverify`.

**Remove it**.

Also code preceded with `!` is **excluded**, and you have excluded these optimizations `!code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/allocation/variable`

You can use `*` to match any part of optimizations.

Please check [android-proguard usage](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/proguard/docs/index.html#manual/usage.html).

Comment: I removed but I still has the same result

Comment: No change, could you please edit your answer by adding a WORKING example? I would do appreciate it!
Am I doing something wrong? I generating the release APK in Studio by clicking: Build -> Generate Signed APK -> choose release flavor  and that's it.

Comment: @Karoly It should work after this maintain, be sure that your `proguard-android-optimize.txt` in the right place `dir/build/intermediates/proguard-files`.

Comment: Also if you are using flavor be sure that you handle it  `productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
        }
        flavor2 {
            proguardFile 'flavor2-rules.pro'
        }
    }`

Comment: I’ll check for sure thanks. Just a quick question: why should I place into the build folder ? That’s getting deleted . I’m using sdk/tools/proguard

Comment: @Karoly when you build your project, the plugin makes a copy of this file int that `path`.

Comment: ok, I wasn't able to remove the logs. What I did created a new class and using if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){} and all Log.x has been modified to MyLogger.x , where x = method name. Thanks for your help @Ibrahim